# Creating an HTML form to interact with REST API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, rest

I am trying to write an HTML form to interact with a REST API.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure what I need to do to actually get it to interact with the REST API, how do I link them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
<label for="name">Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>

<label for="password">Password</label><br>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. First of all, your `form` needs to be submittable. You can achieve this by adding a `submit` `input`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
<label for="name">Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>

<label for="password">Password</label><br>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
```

Now, your structure is ready to be used. On the other end, you have a RESTful API, which should handle properly the request your form is sending. You can achieve that using the `action` attribute of your `form` tag.